# GBA Emulator for iPad

Tags: ios, emulation, game-boy-advance

Is there an iPad emulator for the Gameboy Advance? I don't want to jailbreak my phone.

I am using the new iPad.

Comment: Yes, look up GBA4iOS. It can be installed without a jailbreak.

Answer (score 4):

Apple does not allow emulators on its App Store.

The only way for you to get an emulator would be to jailbreak your iPad. A GBA emulator for the iPod Touch(not sure for iPad) is gpSPhone.

Keep in mind that ROMs for commercial games can be ILLEGAL whether you own the game or not. In some jurisdictions, it is not illegal to rip a cartridge that you own yourself.

There are websites hosting freeware and non-commercial ROMs. Below is a question taken from a FAQ of one of those websites, linked HERE (I have removed the link because while it wasn't hosting commercial ROMs, it had links to sites which did).

> Are ROMS illegal?
>
> Commercial roms - YES - downloading / sharing / distributing etc IS
>   indeed ILLEGAL. BUT **Under Section 117 of the US Copyright Law** You have
>   a right to: (a) Making of Additional Copy or Adaptation by Owner of
>   Copy. -
>
> Notwithstanding the provisions of section 106, it is not an
>   infringement for the owner of a copy of a computer program to make or
>   authorize the making of another copy or adaptation of that computer
>   program provided:
>
> (1) that such a new copy or adaptation is created as an essential step
>   in the utilization of the computer program in conjunction with a
>   machine and that it is used in no other manner, or
>
> (2) that such new copy or adaptation is for archival purposes only and
>   that all archival copies are destroyed in the event that continued
>   possession of the computer program should cease to be rightful.
>
> AND
>
> **Freeware and Public Domain (PD) ROMS are not made by NINTENDO or its
>   partners and they are LEGAL. In most cases they are made as freeware,
>   shareware or demos and legalized for free use by their authors. It is
>   100% legal for people play such roms on emulators or gba flash cards.**

Comment: "Keep in mind that ROMs for commercial games are ILLEGAL." As there is no encryption on GBA cartridges, it is legal to rip your own cartridges in many jurisdictions.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig, I didn't know that.. Will update my answer. Thanks.. :-)

Comment: While it is true that in some jurisdictions it is legal to rip your own cartridges, in *no* jurisdiction, (other than those that are not party to the Berne Convention, so Afghanistan, Angola, Cambodia, Iran, Iraq, etc.), is it legal to distribute a ROM. So no, there are no websites that host legal rom downloads.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, I have updated my answer with a question from a FAQ of one of those legal ROM download sites.